# What's the Benefit of Catching an Exception and Throw it Early?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

In which case catching an exception and throw it early is better?

For demonstrations:

In the case of PUT Request, Should I check the existence of an entity before setting its state to modified? Or let it throw an exception in case the entity doesn't exist?

Case 1: (There is only one request to the database, which will throw an exception in case the entity doesn't exist)

```
public async Task UpdateNotificationSitting(NotificationSittingVM model)
{
    NotificationSittingEntity entity = _mapper.Map<NotificationSittingVM, NotificationSittingEntity>(model);

    _notificationSittingRepository.Update(entity);
    await _notificationSittingRepository.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

Case 2 (There are two requests to the database, but i have the ability to throw the exception earlier):

```
public async Task UpdateNotificationSitting(long id, NotificationSittingVM model)
{
    if (_notificationSittingRepository.GetById(id) == null)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException($"Notification Sitting with Id: {id}, not exisit.");
    }

    NotificationSittingEntity entity = _mapper.Map<NotificationSittingVM, NotificationSittingEntity>(model);

    _notificationSittingRepository.Update(entity);
    await _notificationSittingRepository.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

Comment: If you can throw a more specific, helpful, exception than the one that will come down the line you should absolutely do that. Is my opinion. Additionally, you should fail fast and early.

Comment: There's no _correct_ answer here. If your client needs to know whether the item existed, let it know. If it doesn't care, it's up to you to decide how you want the API to behave. The client is free to "not care".

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen
"Additionally, you should fail fast and early." Could you please tell me why?

Comment: @KirkLarkin 
A good point to mention, thanks.

Comment: Well, if you're driving down a long road, a road that has no exits, and is eventually going to stop with a blockade due to a ruptured water pipe and the work to rectify this, would you like to know this problem before your last chance to turn off that road, or would you like to wait until you hit the blockade? Don't let got trundle on if you already "know" or can detect that it will eventually fail anyway. We're not creating code that "Oh, it might actually work ... I hope", computers are a bit more predictable than that.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Amazing answer!! Thanks a lot.

Comment: It is better to spend 0 cpu cycles, and then fail, than it is to spend 1000 cpu cycles, and then fail. Also, my comment about a more specific exception also stands. Usually, "eventually fail" is often a NullReferenceException or similar. You already know **that** it is going to fail, but more importantly, you know **why**. So let the client code know this. In this respect I would not even use InvalidOperationException, this is almost as useful/-less as Exception. Either pick a better already known exception, or create your own that more clearer convey the problem back to the client.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen 
That was very clear, thank you for the great information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would most likely want to inform you API client, that the resource doesn't exist.

Maybe instead of throwing the Exception, you just return not found like this:

```
if (_notificationSittingRepository.GetById(id) == null)
{
    return NotFound();
}
```

Then the response will carry 404 status code - informing that the resource doesn't exist, instead of 500 - like it would by default when throwing, without catching the exception

Comment: What is the benefit of returning NotFound instead of throwing an exception?

Comment: It is a different way. One benefit is that it doesn't throw an exception, so it can be ignored. One drawback is that it doesn't throw an exception, so it can be ignored. You will have to decide why you would want to use it, or not.

Comment: If you always throw an exception, without handling it, there will be always 500 status code, for any type of exceptions. In this case you know what the issue is, and you can safely return 404 which is meaningful status code.
500 - means that something went bad on the server, its a general purpose error code.
You error is a application type of exception, you should use the 4XX range Status code, I suggest 404 - not found or 400 - BadRequest, and if you want to handle that exception you can always to that before the `return` statement

Comment: The way you explain things is more than awesome, you should think about being an instructor. Thanks again. @LasseV.Karlsen

Comment: @kebek
Very useful, thank you!

Comment: hah, thank you, actually I'm currently ending my second course on .NET Core web API, first one is already on udemy :P